# why does one side of the curve get this weird inflated look but not the other side?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, vertices, conversion

I have made a wire-mesh usng verts, then converted it into a curve. I then tried applying some depth to it using the bevel option on the curve. On the curve however, one side of it has gotten this weird inflated look:
[image]

[image]

whilst the other side looks normal and like I want it to:

[image]

both sides were identical when I made them using the wire, I even deleted the half that had problems and mirrored the other side over to replace it, but the issue persisted. When I go into the curve in edit mode, there are some weird things going on with the selection too, with the two sides having different ways of connecting to the main frame and stuff.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

it seems like the right side is not connected to the rest of the curve like the left side is, but I have no idea why it is this way, as the sides should be identical.

Comment: Curves are a bit weird like this. You will find that if you try and move a control point that is at the intersection, there will be 2 points on top of each other. Try selecting both, right click and fillet. Play around till you get something that looks nice.